# How do I read specific XML File section - VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

Please take a look at the below XML

```
<MessageHeader>
   <Master branch_name="ABCD" ref_date="2020-09-23 11:43:46" refno="1">
      <mbl_no>1234566</mbl_no>
      <mbl_date>2020-08-25 00:00:00</mbl_date>
      <agent_code>XXXXX</agent_code>
      <agent_name>XXXX YYYYY</agent_name>
      <carrier_code>1234</carrier_code>
      <carrier_name>XXXXX</carrier_name>
      <pol_code>XXX1234</pol_code>
      <pol_name>XXXX,YYYY</pol_name>
      <HouseBill> 
        <House slno="1" house_no="XXDEL233695">
          <shipper_code>3023233324</shipper_code>
          <shipper_name>..Shipper Name...</shipper_name>
          <shipper_add1>... Address 1... </shipper_add1>
          <shipper_add2>... Address 2...</shipper_add2>
          <shipper_add3/>
          <shipper_add4/>
        </House>
     </HouseBill>
   </Master>
</MessageHeader>
```

I am trying to read this information in to a Dataset using the below code:

```
Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
Dim importFileName As String = "C:\107.xml"
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(importFileName, New XmlReaderSettings())
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
```

This works great for me and I can access the columns as such:

```
Dim shipperName As String = ds.tables("House").rows(x).Item("shipper_name").tostring()
```

My question is how would I access the items such as slno and house_no items from the parent node?

Thanks

Comment: Why dataset?  VB .Net does an excellent job with XML without resorting to a dataset.

Comment: I'm adapting some existing code to incorporate a different xml layout and it's faster for me.

Comment: Just in case I've supplied an answer that doesn't use dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without dataset

```
    Dim xmlFile As XElement
    Dim importFileName As String = "C:\107.xml"
    ' xmlFile = XElement.Load(importFileName)

    'for testing use litersl
    xmlFile = <MessageHeader>
                  <Master branch_name="ABCD" ref_date="2020-09-23 11:43:46" refno="1">
                      <mbl_no>1234566</mbl_no>
                      <mbl_date>2020-08-25 00:00:00</mbl_date>
                      <agent_code>XXXXX</agent_code>
                      <agent_name>XXXX YYYYY</agent_name>
                      <carrier_code>1234</carrier_code>
                      <carrier_name>XXXXX</carrier_name>
                      <pol_code>XXX1234</pol_code>
                      <pol_name>XXXX,YYYY</pol_name>
                      <HouseBill>
                          <House slno="1" house_no="XXDEL233695">
                              <shipper_code>3023233324</shipper_code>
                              <shipper_name>..Shipper Name...</shipper_name>
                              <shipper_add1>... Address 1... </shipper_add1>
                              <shipper_add2>... Address 2...</shipper_add2>
                              <shipper_add3/>
                              <shipper_add4/>
                          </House>
                      </HouseBill>
                  </Master>
              </MessageHeader>

    Dim shipperName As String = xmlFile.<Master>.<HouseBill>.<House>.<shipper_name>.Value
    Dim slno As String = xmlFile.<Master>.<HouseBill>.<House>.@slno
    Dim house_no As String = xmlFile.<Master>.<HouseBill>.<House>.@house_no
```

for production

```
    Dim xmlFile As XElement
    Dim importFileName As String = "C:\107.xml"
    xmlFile = XElement.Load(importFileName)

    Dim shipperName As String = xmlFile.<Master>.<HouseBill>.<House>.<shipper_name>.Value
    Dim slno As String = xmlFile.<Master>.<HouseBill>.<House>.@slno
    Dim house_no As String = xmlFile.<Master>.<HouseBill>.<House>.@house_no
```

Comment: Each of those values return nothing when testing. I should add this is only part of the XML file if it makes a difference.

Comment: You should show something representative of the data.  If you run the code using the literal it works/

Comment: You're right. If I run the testing code it works. If I run the production code each value is nothing. This may be to do with other elements that I didn't include in my original post.


Looking at the complete stucture it looks like:

<Master branchname="xyz" ref="123">
<houseBill><House slno="1"

Does this make more sense? It's a pretty big XML file I only inlcuded the above as I went with the dataset option

Comment: I've supplied more details of how the full file really looks

Comment: DataSet will not work.. It will fragment results into a lot of DataTables that really cannot be used.  You can only use the DataSet ReadXml when the number of descendants does not exceed 4.  The root tag is used and the DataSet Name.  The first children are the Table Names.  The second children are the column names.  The fourth Children are the row data.  You have six layers of tags and the results are a lot of DataTables with pieces of the data in each table.

Comment: I can get access to every single piece of data from the XML file using a dataset except the data that is inside the <house        > element

Comment: @user3608638 - Updated the code above based on the NEW format provided.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Just another question sorry. If I have multiple rows in the house element what would be the best way to read that?

Comment: @user3608638 you'll have to be a little clearer.  This might interest you, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/overview-of-linq-to-xml